# phpBB 3 - How to put a user in a specific group depending on registration field?

Tags: customization, phpbb, phpbb3

first question here so please forgive me if I make mistakes.

My problem is the following:
I've got my phpBB3 forum with 2 groups of users defined by me. I want to put users in one of those groups depending on the value of a custom registration field that I added. 
I can't find out how to do this.

Maybe I'm missing something there, any help is welcome. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPBB3 can't do this out of the box. However, the [Groups on Registration and Custom Profile Fields](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=1880555) appears to do what you are looking to do.

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel this answers your question remember to mark it as an answer too.